# Let $\mathbb S^1 = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}.$ Does either one of the following homeomorphisms hold?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb S^1 = \{ (x,y) : x^2 + y^2 = 1 \}.$ Does either one of the following homeomorphisms hold?

1. $\mathbb S^1 \cong(0,1)$
2. $\mathbb S \cong [0,1]$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If $\phi:X \rightarrow Y$ is a homeomorphism and $X$ is connected, then $Y$ is also connected.

If there were a homeomorphism $\phi:S^1 \rightarrow [0, 1]$ or $\phi:S^1 \rightarrow (0, 1)$, then its restriction to $S^1 \setminus \{x\}$ would give a homeomorphism to $[0, 1] \setminus \{ \phi(x) \}$.  But notice that $S^1 \setminus \{x\}$ is connected for any given $x \in S^1$, and the same cannot be said for $[0, 1]$ or $(0, 1)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you perhaps explain to me how we can see that $S^1 \setminus \{x \}$ is connected? I'm self studying this work so it can be somewhat confusing at times

Comment: Sure @user229672.  Path connectedness implies connectedness, so we'll show that $S^1 \setminus \{x \}$ is path connected.  This is easy enough to see intuitively, but for sake of rigor suppose you are given two points $u, v \in S^1 \setminus \{x\}$.  you can construct the function $[0, 1] \rightarrow S^1 \setminus \{x\}$ by starting with a function $f(\theta) = [ \cos( \theta), \sin( \theta)]$ for $\theta$ in the appropriate interval, then shifting the domain to $[0, 1]$ so that $f(0) = u$ and $f(1) = v$:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connected_space#Path_connectedness